# Having trouble building SDL Project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, build, sdl

I have started work on SDL. I am having troubles with a basic program, every time i compile it i get no errors, but the program is completely blank. The Build Succeeds, and the application icon pops up into my dock, but stays open for 5 seconds with no window. The code is below:

```
    //
//  main.cpp
//  HelloSDL
//
//  Created by Liam Tan
//  Copyright 2014 Liam Tan. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;
//Declares surfaces
SDL_Surface* message = NULL;
SDL_Surface* background = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

SDL_Surface *load_image( std::string filename) {
    //declaration
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;
    //takes arguement and loads that BMP
    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(filename.c_str() );
    //Checks, swaps opti with loaded then frees loaded
    if (loadedImage!= NULL) {
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat (loadedImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }
    return optimizedImage;
}
void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination) {
    //temporary rectangle to hold offsets
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, NULL);
}

int SDL_main (int argc, char **argv) {
    const std::string errorMsg = "failed to initialize. ";
    //Initialise
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1 ) {
        std::cout << "SDL " << errorMsg << std::endl;
        SDL_GetError();
        return 1;
    }
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    if (screen == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Video mode " << errorMsg << std::endl;
        SDL_GetError();
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Programming", NULL);
    //loads message
    message = load_image("textures/hello.bmp");
    //loads background
    background = load_image("textures/background.bmp");
    //blits 4 times!
    apply_surface(0,0,background,screen);
    apply_surface( 320, 0, background, screen );
    apply_surface( 0, 240, background, screen );
    apply_surface( 320, 240, background, screen );
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Xcode 5, and SDL 1.2.

Comment: Are syou sure SDL finds your images? Try adding and `else` after `if (loadedImage!= NULL){}` and put a debug message so you know if something goes wrong. 
I also suggest learning SDL2 instead of SDL1.2. SDL2 is a lot better to work with. For instance, you don't have to use `SDL_BlitSurface()` to render

Comment: @olevegard I added an SDL_GetError else in and it still does nothing. I actually added a build phase with a new directory for the images and put them in that way: in theory, this should all work.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a few problems in your code. They may not be all errors.

1) When you blit an image it doesn't go directly to the screen. It is kept in a buffer until you call `SDL_Flip(screen);`

So the last few lines should be like that

```
...
apply_surface( 320, 240, background, screen );
SDL_Flip(screen);//Display the results of the blits
SDL_Delay(5000);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
```

2) You don't use `Rect offset` when you blit your image. It will always be displayed at the 0,0 position.

```
//temporary rectangle to hold offsets
SDL_Rect offset;
offset.x = x;
offset.y = y;
SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, NULL);
```

3) You never free the images you load. you need to put some `SDL_FreeSurface(...);` before SDL_Quit.

4) You load but never use `hello.bmp`

Also, I don't see why you declare your surfaces as global. But maybe you have a good reason.

You can also try to replace your `SDL_Delay(5000);` by

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)//we wait until done == true
{

    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_WaitEvent(&event))//we get all the events
    {
        switch (event.type) //we look what type of event we received
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:  //We received a quit event
            done = true;//we want to exit the loop
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Because SDL_Delay tells your computer your application doesn't have to been updated for the amount of time.